# Java API documentation #reference problem

Tags: documentation, java

Looking at the latest (as of 21-Sep-2018) Java API documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html

If you type "Collectors.toList" in the search box, it takes you to:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

(Same problem with any other search that contains an internal reference (i.e. to a method, not a class.)

As you can see, the problem is that the URL it takes you to ends in `#toList--` while the correct place is actually located at `#toList()`. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Report it there: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/

Comment: If it is an issue, it is an issue with a particular vendor's website ... not a programming or software development problem.  IMO, this is question is off-topic.

Comment: Very similar bugs already reported: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8200075, https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8199278

Comment: @StephenC good point, but is the Java API documentation available for OpenJDK, or is it only available in vendor-specific formats?

Comment: @mzjn thanks for that. It seems it's been fixed in the jdk11 early access.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - That is also off-topic :-).  But the answer is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk10-readme-4419830.html#documentation

Comment: @StephenC thanks but your link only seems to be about Oracle documentation. Also, I don't see how this is off-topic. I'm not asking for specifically Oracle documentation. It's just that Oracle's documentation seems to be the only online Java API documentation available. I don't care which vendor it comes from. I'm a Java developer and I'm looking for usable API documentation to help me with my coding. I don't see any other documentation other than Oracle's. I guess Adopt OpenJDK have a build-it-yourself one but not an online one.

Comment: 1) The link explains how to download your own copy of the documentation.  *"To obtain the documentation bundle visit the Java SE download page."* (Linked in original) 2)  Since the javadocs are generated from the same source code, there is no distinction between Oracle and OpenJDK. 3) Requesting an off-site resource is off topic.  Complaining about a vendor's website search functionality is off-topic.